# How to make Splunk query case sensitive

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

How do I make my query case sensitive.

Say I want my search results for `"Case Sensitive"` and not `"CASE sensitive"` or `"CASE SENSITIVE"`

This is what I'm using which isn't helping.

```
index=foo_foo sourcetype=foo "Is my query CASE(Case Sensitive)"
```

I've tried using `CASE(Case Sensitive)` but that didn't help me get the results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect Splunk is interpreting your search string literally so is not seeing CASE as a function.

Try this:

```
index=foo_foo sourcetype=foo "Is my query "CASE(Case Sensitive)
```